# The State of Movies 2015-2016

Tags: discussion

Inspired to keep the trend going  from [Stats on RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6692/statistics-on-rpg-se-questions-closed-and-reopened-in-2016?cb=1), I have rounded up some statistics for Movies for 2015 and 2016.

[image: Stats for Movies 2015 to 2016]

Comment: I don't know how to create tables on here, but if someone wants to do it, I can provide the excel document I created for this

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not really a way to make tables in posts... You can do it manually using ASCII art but you can't use HTML tables so a screenshot may be the best option. See [this MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) for info.

Comment: one statistic of interest to note is that, while the total number of id questions rose 17%, their ratio to total questions asked dropped 4%.

Comment: How did you gather those stats. It would be very interesting what measures you actually used to count those. Since the SEDE stats are a little lacking in this regard.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I used the SEDE, but sadly it didn't save my queries...

Comment: Wow... Deleting 2/5 questions that are asked... that's scary.

Comment: @Catija Yeah but 45% of questions are ID....and those are notoriously bad.

Comment: @Paulie_D Though thanks to our diligent mods and members, the ID that actually *remains* in the site is only 15%. ;)

Comment: Why is the number of closed questions so low compared to the number of deleted questions?  Does that mean the majority of question deletions (which I assume are mostly not self-deletions by OPs) that occur on this stack are done without close reviews?

Comment: @faintsignal I'd have to dig to see if I could answer that.  from what I saw, they're either self-deletions or questions that were vtc'd that were deleted by either the automatic process or by mods/those with delete powers

Comment: @DForck42 I guess we need to clarify what we're looking at. Perhaps the explanation must be that the stats on Closed questions do not include those that were deleted.

Comment: @faintsignal that is correct.  in this data being deleted excludes it from the next three categories.  each category is exclusive.  either it's in that category, or it's in another.

Comment: Ok. I guess it's my nature to expect to see the full close stats in that 2nd section. Still, very informative, thanks.

Comment: I suggest adding the ID tag as it's very much relevant